# React router redirects the page but component doesn't get rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a strange problem with rendering a component while Route changes.
Versions I use

```
{
  "react": "16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "16.9.0",
  "react-router-dom": "5.1.0"
}
```

This is my route configuration

```
const Routes = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = StorageManager.get('session');
    return (
        <>
            <div className="background"></div>
            <MainLayout>
                <Header />
                <LeftSidebarMenu />
                <main className="main-container">
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/categories" />
                            <Route exact path='/categories' component={Home} />
                            <Route exact path='/categories/new' component={CreateCategory} />
                            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}
                                />
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </main>
            </MainLayout>
        </>
    );
};

export default Routes;
```

The main problem is that, when a user clicks login/logout, in case of success/failure, it should redirect the user to the appropriate page. Actually the route changes, but the component doesn't get rendered. I use *history.push(PATH)* for redirecting users. I am not a beginner in react and to be honest, the first time I am faced with this kind of strange problem. Maybe I confused something with my router configs.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {withRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import {shallowEqual, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import Button from '../../components/core/button';
import StorageManager from '../../helpers/utilities/storageManager';
import FormGroup from '../../components/core/form/form-group';
import useForm from '../../helpers/custom-hooks';
import {signInRequest} from '../../redux/actions';

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

const Header = (props) => {
    const actionResult = useSelector((state) => state.admin.actionResult, shallowEqual);

    const {handleInputChange, handleSubmit} = useForm(signInRequest);
    const [session, setSession] = useState(StorageManager.get('session'));
    const [isLoginModalOpen, toggleLoginModal] = useState(false);
    const toggleModal = () => toggleLoginModal(!isLoginModalOpen);

    const handleLogin = () => {
        handleSubmit();
    };

    if(actionResult && actionResult.type === 'success' && isLoginModalOpen){
        setSession(StorageManager.get('session'));
        toggleLoginModal(false);
        props.history.push('/categories');
    }

    const handleLogout = () => {
        props.history.push('/login');
        StorageManager.remove('session');
        // setSession('');
    };

    return (
        <header className="header-section clearfix">
            <div className="header-container">
                <div className="header-left-menu">
                    <div className='header-logo-box'>
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src={require('../../images/logo.png')} alt=""/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Link to='/categories'>Link</Link>
                <div className="header-right-menu">
                    <div className="user-settings">
                        <img src={require('../../images/user.png')} alt=""/>
                        <span>Username</span>
                        {
                            session ?
                            <Button
                            className='btn-medium'
                            text='Выход'
                            onClick={handleLogout}
                        /> :
                        <Button
                            className='btn-medium'
                            text='Логин'
                            onClick={toggleModal}
                        />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Modal
                isOpen={isLoginModalOpen}
                style={customStyles}
                shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
                onRequestClose={toggleModal}
                contentLabel="Login Modal"
            >
                <FormGroup className='form-group__modal'>
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="login"
                        name="login"
                        className='form-input'
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <h3>Password</h3>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="password"
                        name="password"
                        className='form-input'
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <Button
                        text='Sign in'
                        onClick={handleLogin}
                    />
                    <div className='invalid'>{actionResult ? actionResult.message : ''}</div>
                </FormGroup>
            </Modal>
        </header>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

Comment: You have missed the '/' in the second Route Tag it should be `/categories/new`

Comment: That was just a typo. The actual problem is not related to it

Comment: Doest it help of you remove `exact` from all the routes inside the `Switch`?

Comment: Did you try the route by writing it manually in the address bar whether it works or not?

Comment: When it redirects, it only renders that page after refreshing. My component doesn't even mount. Yes if manually enter, it reloads the page and everything is working good

Comment: Can you share the code though which your redirect, also which history object areyou using

Comment: try to wrap your routes in Browser router imported from   ` import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: @SaqibNaseeb The same result.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have tried everything.
1. <Link to='/categories'>Link</Link>
2. <button onClick={() => props.history.push(''/path)}></button>

Comment: kindly share the code of the part where you are pushing the route in history

Comment: @SaqibNaseeb I have updated

Comment: As you can see, the Header component is not a direct part of routing, I have wrapped it with `withRouter` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the place where you wish to take an action is not wrapped by a Router provider. Even if you use withRouter which is an HOC that tried to get the router props from the nearest provider of Routes, it won't get you the history props from your Router that is used to wrap all your Routes.

You need to update how you wrap your components with Router like

```
const Routes = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = StorageManager.get('session');
    return (
        <>
           <div className="background"></div>
           <Router history={history}>
            <MainLayout>
                <Header />
                <LeftSidebarMenu />
                <main className="main-container">
                        <Switch>
                            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/categories" />
                            <Route exact path='/categories' component={Home} />
                            <Route exact path='/categories/new' component={CreateCategory} />
                            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}
                                />
                        </Switch>
                </main>
            </MainLayout>
          </Router>
        </>
    );
};

export default Routes;
```