# React-router Redirection displays page only when reloading it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router in a react app and I faced an issue while launching the app. First, I got a blank page without any error, when i reload the page I got the content.

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Root from './app/Root';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './app/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Root />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Root.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import SignIn from 'features/authentication/signIn/SignInContainer';
import SignUp from 'features/authentication/signUp/SignUpContainer';
import history from 'browserHistory/index';
const Root = (): JSX.Element => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
   </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default Root;
```

When I tried the `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router` I hadn't the issue but BrowserRouter does not work if I use `history.push()` outside a tsx files. That's why I need to use `Router` instead.
There is a similar question [React router redirects the page but component doesn't get rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762334/react-router-redirects-the-page-but-component-doesnt-get-rendered) but I think that my Router wrap the main app components. What did I misconfigured in the code?

Comment: Can you share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code seems correct as `Router` works after providing it a [history object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66876991/2873538).

So, make sure you have properly created `history`:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

And, also ensure that you are using [version 4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/42933fe141819e4662113ab2c320bf86be3490fb/packages/react-router-dom/package.json#L44) of `history`, not [version 5 (open issue)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804).

Comment: I'm using `createBrowserHistory` as you mentioned but I was using history v5.0.0 I downgraded to v4.10.1 and it works well now.