# Why will history.push not redirect to a new component using react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 components both are exactly the same. one is redirected to when I click on a Navlink inside of my navbar that I created using react-bootstrap. The other component that is exactly the same won't load when I click on the html button that should redirect to that component. Please help me.

the html button and the function to redirect look like

```
const getProfile = async (member) => {
 //   const addr = dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
    console.log(member)
    history.push('/member')

}

    <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
```

The routes.js looks like

```
const Routes = (props) => {
  return (
      <Switch>

      <Route path="/member" exact component={Member} /> 

      </Switch>
    
  )
}

export default Routes
```

The component that I am trying to redirect to is exactly the same as one that is redirected to and working when I click on it from the navlink

Comment: *One works, one doesn't and both are exactly the same*. It seems impossible. There must be differences. And, to fix it, we would need a [minimal & complete example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: There were some differences but I just copied and pasted the other component to ust try and get the redirect working. When I click the button it redirects but doesn't load but shows everything it should in the console.log. When I refresh the page it loads.

Comment: Make sure the [versions are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538). [Another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66926942/2873538).